# Rails.cache error in Rails 3.1 - TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I running into an issue with the Rails.cache methods on 3.1.0.rc4 (ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10]).  The code works fine within the same application on 2.3.12 (ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03), but started returning an error following the upgrade.  I haven't been able to figure out why yet.

The error seems to occur when trying to cache objects that have more than one scope on them.

Also, any scopes using lambdas fail regardless of how many scopes.

I have hit failures from these patterns:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("keyname", :expires_in => 1.minute) do
    Model.scope_with_lambda
end


Rails.cache.fetch("keyname", :expires_in => 1.minute) do
    Model.scope.scope
end
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:627:in `dump'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:627:in `should_compress?'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:559:in `initialize'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:363:in `new'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:363:in `block in write'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:520:in `instrument'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:362:in `write'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache.rb:299:in `fetch'
    from (irb):62
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /project/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried using the :raw => true option as an alternative, but that isn't working because the Rails.cache.fetch blocks are attempting to cache objects.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you cache a scope? Wouldn't it be better to cache the actual data? Try adding the `all` method in the end of each scope. `Model.scope_with_lambda.all`

Comment: @Oleander - yep, based on the response below, it seems we got lucky with storing the model objects into cache before. We'll recode to cache the data as opposed to the objects.  Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This might be a little verbose but I had to spend some time with the Rails source code to learn how the caching internals work. Writing things down aids my understanding and I figure that sharing some notes on how things work can't hurt. Skip to the end if you're in a hurry.

---

## Why It Happens

This is the offending method inside ActiveSupport:

```
def should_compress?(value, options)
  if options[:compress] && value
    unless value.is_a?(Numeric)
      compress_threshold = options[:compress_threshold] || DEFAULT_COMPRESS_LIMIT
      serialized_value = value.is_a?(String) ? value : Marshal.dump(value)
      return true if serialized_value.size >= compress_threshold   
    end
  end
  false  
end
```

Note the assignment to `serialized_value`. If you poke around inside `cache.rb`, you'll see that it uses [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html) to serialize objects to byte strings before they go into the cache and then Marshal again to deserialize objects. The compression issue isn't important here, the important thing is the use of Marshal.

The problem [is that](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html):

> Some objects cannot be dumped: if the objects to be dumped include bindings, procedure or method objects, instances of class IO, or singleton objects, a TypeError will be raised.

Some things have state (such as OS file descriptors or blocks) that can't be serialized by Marshal. The error you're noting is this:

> can't dump hash with default proc

So someone in your model has an instance variable that is a Hash and that Hash uses a block to supply default values. The `column_methods_hash` method uses such a Hash and even caches the Hash inside `@dynamic_methods_hash`; `column_methods_hash` will be called (indirectly) by public methods such as `respond_to?` and `method_missing`.

One of `respond_to?` or `method_missing` will probably get called on every AR model instance sooner or later and calling either method makes your object unserializable. So, AR model instances are essentially unserializable in Rails 3.

Interestingly enough, the `respond_to?` and `method_missing` implementations in 2.3.8 are also backed by a Hash that uses a block for default values. The 2.3.8 cache is ["[...]is meant for caching strings."](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store) so you were getting lucky with a backend that could handle whole objects or it used Marshal before your objects had hash-with-procs in them; or perhaps you were using the [`MemoryStore`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore) cache backend and that's little more than a big Hash.

Using multiple scope-with-lambdas might end up storing Procs in your AR objects; I'd expect the lambdas to be stored with the class (or singleton class) rather than the objects but I didn't bother with an analysis as the problem with `respond_to?` and `method_missing` makes the `scope` issue irrelevant.

## What You Can Do About It

I think you've been storing the wrong things in your cache and getting lucky. You can either start using the Rails cache properly (i.e. store simple generated data rather than whole models) or you can implement the `marshal_dump`/`marshal_load` or `_dump`/`_load` methods as outlined in [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html). Alternatively, you can use one of the MemoryStore backends and limit yourself to one distinct cache per server process.

---

## Executive Summary

You can't depend on storing ActiveRecord model objects in the Rails cache unless you're prepared to handle the marshalling yourself or you want to limit yourself to the MemoryStore cache backends.

---

The exact source of the problem has changed in more recent versions of Rails but there are still many instances of `default_proc`s associated with Hashes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the awesome response!  I think your diagnosis is exactly correct - one of the parameters in the scope was pulling a value from a Hash.  However, I think your larger point that our implementation of Rails.cache should be re-written to avoid storing the model objects directly into the cache. We did get lucky before, but we should use this as an opportunity to clean it up.  I very much appreciate the detailed analysis - it was extremely helpful!

Comment: Was this only caused by the Ruby version change? "Programming Ruby" says of Ruby Marshal "this binary format has one major disadvantage: if the interpreter changes significantly, the marshal binary format my also change, and old dumped files may no longer be loadable." So your 1.8 objects we likely rotten. So this should work with a binary safe backend.

Comment: Oh, marshaling an object will also result in the objects data being serialized, which if it includes an un-marshallabe object will raise an exception. So I suppose Marshall can't even really be relied upon for many complex ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: @mixonic: I think the caching change was the major culprit. AFAIK, the old cache was little more than a list of objects stored in memory as-is, the new one involved serialization. Marshal should only be used for temporary storage or transport, you should use something else for real persistence as the format can change and leave you without any pleasant way to upgrade.

Comment: I'm finding that an empty AR::Relation can't be dumped:

TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class Mutex

Comment: @cpuguy83: I don't know what part of a relation is tied up with threading but I wouldn't expect any database-ish objects to be dumpable,

Comment: @muistooshort, it is weird... I can cache an AR::Relation as long as it's not empty.

Comment: I have found with ActiveRecord objects that if you clear their association_cache then Marshal Loading them becomes much more reliable.  This is what was done with SimpleCacheable https://github.com/flyerhzm/simple_cacheable

Comment: Is there a way to find out what attribute is causing the error? I have run into an issue where `Marshal.dump Brand.first` and `Marshal.dump Brand.new` work as expected, but `Marshal.dump FactoryGirl.create(:brand)` triggers an exception, even though the resulting object is valid and appears identical to all other brand objects. Other model instances instantiated with `FactoryGirl.create` can be dumped OK, but not all models apparently.

Comment: @Chrisbloom7: My advice is to never Marshal AR objects, there are too many sharp edges to make it a sane thing to do. If you need to cache something then you'd be better off using a Struct with the same (read-only) interface as your model.

Comment: FYI: I was running into this issue using the in memory cache. Turns out the in memory cache also marshalls the data https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/714a38217e884418d635435eb658ae7347d08dd7/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L660-L672

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to mu-is-too-short for his excellent analysis. I've managed to get my model to serialize now with this:

```
def marshal_dump
  {}.merge(attributes)
end

def marshal_load stuff
  send :initialize, stuff, :without_protection => true
end
```

I also have some "virtual attributes" set by a direct SQL join query using `AS` e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT posts.*, name from authors AS author_name FROM posts INNER JOIN authors ON author.post_id = posts.id WHERE posts.id = 123`. For these to work I need to declare an `attr_accessor` for each, then dump/load them too, like so:

```
VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES = [:author_name]

attr_accessor *VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES

def marshal_dump
  virtual_attributes = Hash[VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES.map {|col| [col, self.send(col)] }]
  {}.with_indifferent_access.merge(attributes).merge(virtual_attributes)
end

def marshal_load stuff
  stuff = stuff.with_indifferent_access
  send :initialize, stuff, :without_protection => true
  VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES.each do |attribute|
    self.send("#{attribute}=", stuff[attribute])
  end
end
```

Using Rails 3.2.18

Answer (score 3):

I realized that using where or some scope created `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. I then noticed that doing a simple `Model.find` worked. I suspected that it didn't like the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so I forced conversion to a plain `Array` and that worked for me.

```
Rails.cache.fetch([self.id, 'relA']) do
  relA.where(
      attr1: 'some_value'
  ).order(
      'attr2 DESC'
  ).includes(
      :rel_1,
      :rel_2
  ).decorate.to_a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the default proc after you finished altering it. something like:

```
your_hash.default = nil # clear the default_proc
```