# Caching ActiveRecord models (in 3.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Following an upgrade to 3.2.1, I'm getting the following error when attempting to cache activerecord models:

```
TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc
        from .../activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:562:in `dump'
```

The issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391855/rails-cache-error-in-rails-3-1-typeerror-cant-dump-hash-with-default-proc), and I understand that some instance variable on the model is a Hash with a default_proc, which cannot be marshaled.

I've tried some different repos of [cache-fu as a solution](http://codingblock.blogspot.com/2011/07/caching-active-record-models-in-rails-3.html), but it doesn't solve the TypeError issue.  I've also tried implementing my own marshaling, but I don't trust it all the way.

Caching ActiveRecord models seems like a very common thing to want do.  I can't be the only one trying to marshal ActiveRecord models in 3.2.1!  Has anyone else found a decent solution for this?

Comment: It may be a very common want but that doesn't make it a good idea. If something is in your database then you usually expect it to change. When the model changes, you'd have to broadcast that to all the caches to avoid stale cached objects; all that is probably more hassle and expense (especially when you have multiple server boxes) than a simple PK lookup from the database and your time would probably be better spent fixing whatever performance problems your database is having that makes you want to cache things.

Comment: Invalidating stale objects is relatively easy with the help of ActiveRecord::Base#cache_key and using `:touch => true` on belong_to's that need to invalidate another model's cache.

While I can fix the performance to a certain extent, there are certain collections of models that I must build up from multiple expensive queries, so caching the end result (a collection of AR models) is very desirable.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be using the AR objects directly in this case. A separate interface might be better: (1) if X is in the cache then return X; (2) otherwise load through AR, serialize that AR object to a Struct, stuff the Struct into the cache, and return it. Maybe we could help better if you provided more details about what sorts of objects you're building with all these expensive queries.

Comment: You're right, having some other Struct that can be serialized and using that instead is a good solution.  If I'm unable to cache ActiveRecord objects, that's probably what I'll end up doing.  However, it'd be ideal to have a real ActiveRecord instance, aware of its associations,  validation, and database connection, when I'm done pulling the thing out of the cache.  Serializing a struct of attributes of the model is equivalent to writing my own ActiveRecord model serialization, and I'd prefer not to do that if another solution exists.

Comment: In my particular case, I'm building a collection of [versioned](https://github.com/EricSites/vestal_versions) models that requires multiple expensive queries to generate.  This can be optimized, but it's still desirable to cache the end result (a collection of ActiveRecord models).