# Marshal or Serialize an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, redis, marshalling

I'm using rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

I have a need to store data in Redis for caching purposes. The data element I want to save is a hash of different types of elements -- some of which are currently ActiveRecord objects.

I want to store this compound object in redis (an in-memory key/value store). To do so I need to serialize / deserialize the compound object in a way that brings it back together correctly.

How can I serialize or marshal this hash so it comes back together into the same set of objects when I pull it out of cache?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am losing symbols in my ruby hash when I unmarshal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Marshal.dump(obj) and Marshal.load(marshal_str). [Here are the DOCS](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html)

Comment: Note that there's a problem with using Marshal on ActiveRecord model objects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391855/rails-cache-error-in-rails-3-1-typeerror-cant-dump-hash-with-default-proc   Not sure if it's been fixed in Rails 4