# Rails - 'can't dump hash with default proc' during custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 models. `User` and `Want`. A `User` `has_many:` `Want`s.

The `Want` model has a single property besides `user_id`, that's `name`.

I have written a custom validation in the `Want` model so that a user cannot submit to create 2 wants with the same name:

```
validate :existing_want

  private

    def existing_want
      return unless errors.blank?       
      errors.add(:existing_want, "you already want that") if user.already_wants? name
    end
```

The `already_wants?` method is in the User model:

```
def already_wants? want_name
  does_want_already = false
  self.wants.each { |w| does_want_already = true if w.name == want_name }
  does_want_already
end
```

The validation specs pass in my model tests, but my feature tests fail when i try and submit a duplicate to the `create` action in the `WantsController`:

```
def create
    @want = current_user.wants.build(params[:want])
    if @want.save
      flash[:success] = "success!"
      redirect_to user_account_path current_user.username
    else
      flash[:validation] = @want.errors
      redirect_to user_account_path current_user.username
    end
  end
```

**The error I get:** *can't dump hash with default proc*

No stack trace that leads to my code.

I have narrowed the issue down to this line:

```
self.wants.each { |w| does_want_already = true if w.name == want_name }
```

if I just return `true` regardless the error shows in my view as I would like.

I don't understand? What's wrong? and why is it so cryptic?

Thanks.

Comment: Is something trying to dump an ActiveRecord object? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6391855/479863

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a stack trace (does it lead anywhere, or does it just not appear?) it is difficult to know what exactly is happening, but here's how you can reproduce this error in a clean environment:

```
# initialize a new hash using a block, so it has a default proc
h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = k } 

# attempt to serialize it:
Marshal.dump(h)
#=> TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc
```

Ruby can't serialize procs, so it wouldn't be able to properly reconstitute that serialized hash, hence the error.

If you're reasonably sure that line is the source of your trouble, try refactoring it to see if that solves the problem.

```
def already_wants? want_name
  wants.any? {|want| want_name == want.name }
end
```

or

```
def already_wants? want_name
  wants.where(name: want_name).count > 0
end
```

Comment: aha, your answer made me look at this line: flash[:validation] = @want.errors, which appears to be a culprit too. Thanks. I'll work on it tomorrow and mark correct when I have solved.

Comment: Thanks for the refactoring too, i'm a noob to Ruby