# Clone/copy ActiveRecord::Base instance including attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### The Problem

I'm in the position where I need two *ActiveRecord::Base* instances of the same record.

The requirements of the copy are simple:

1. Both instances must represent the same record.
2. I should be able to change attributes of one instance without effecting the other instance.

### *#dup* and *#clone*

My first thought was to use *#dup* or *#clone*, but these methods have the following issues:

- *#dup* creates a new record. See: [*ActiveRecord::Core#dup*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup)
- *#clone* creates a "shallow" copy. Meaning that if I change an attribute on the copy this attribute is also changed on the original object. See: [*ActiveRecord::Core#clone*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-clone)

### Current Solutions

I have currently 2 solutions for my problem, but they don't feel quite right.

1. `some_object_copy = SomeObject.find(some_object.id)`

   This solution creates an extra query to the database, with `some_object` already in memory this shouldn't be needed.
2. `some_object_copy = SomeObject.instantiate(some_object.attributes)`

   This solution looks way too cumbersome. I feel like there should be a cleaner way of creating a copy.

**Is there a cleaner way of solving this issue?**

Comment: What about marshalling? `some_object_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(some_object))`

Comment: @tbuehlmann It isn't that simple, [models can't be marshalled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392704/479863) as they're littered with non-mashallable procs (unless that has changed recently) so you'd have to write your own load/dump methods.

Comment: Worked for me with a very basic model, but you might be right. Johan, worth a shot?

Comment: why not use `.dup` and then set the ID yourself? It wouldn't save the duped record into the DB. Both will now represent the same record.

Comment: @emaillenin If I set the id it is still marked as new record. This means `new_record?` returns `true` and `persisted?` will return `false`. This could lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: `SomeObject.find(some_object.id)` shouldn't go to DB again. It would be read from the cache if within the same request.