# Ruby : How to record an object and reuse it for tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby-on-Rails, how to record an object and its state (in development mode) so that I can use it for testing purpose ? For example the request object, but more generally any complicated object, whether I own the class definition or not.

Comment: When you say "request object", are you talking about HTTP requests or something else? If the former, [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) is a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `Marshal`, which is built into ruby natively (i.e., not specific to Rails). You can use `Marshal` to serialize objects to strings via `serialized_obj = Marshal.dump(my_object)`. You can store those strings in files and then deserialize them in your test suite via `my_obj = Marshal.load(serialized_obj)`. Here's an example from this great writeup by Mehdi Farsi, https://blog.appsignal.com/2019/03/26/object-marshalling-in-ruby.html.

```
hello_world = 'hello world!'

serialized_string = Marshal.dump(hello_world) # => "\x04\bI\"\x11hello world!\x06:\x06ET"
serialized_string.class                       # => String

deserialized_hello_world = Marshal.load(serialized_string) # => "hello world!"

hello_world.object_id              # => 70204420126020
deserialized_hello_world.object_id # => 70204419825700
```

Comment: One downside of Marshal is that it can't serialize everything ([hashes with `default_proc`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392704/479863) for example). Another is that the format is tied to the version of Ruby. Generally fine for short term storage of simple objects though.